# Solución para albergar una lista de millones de bytes

Tags: java, byte

Estoy teniendo el problema de que tengo que albergar una lista de bytes enorme un una instancia de una clase. La clase original es mas compleja, pero para resumir el problema sería algo así.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class ContendorDeBytes {

    private List<Byte> bytes;

    public ContenerdorDeBytes(){
        bytes = new LinkedList<>();
    }
    
    public List<Byte> getBytes(){
        return bytes;
    }
    
    public void add(byte byteInfo){
        bytes.add(byteInfo);
    }
}
```

La cuestión es que esto resulta problemático para el uso de memoria, en general los test unitarios terminan por falta de memoria. En promedio esta lista alberga 3 millones de bytes.
Ahora bien en realidad las variables de tipo byte contienen valores que van desde -128 hasta 127. Es decir, que todas las posibilidades de mi lista son solo 256 valores.
¿Es posible ahorrar memoria si a la hora de agregar elementos en lugar de agregarlos creandose una nueva instancia de un objeto Byte se colocase en la lista una instancia ya creada?

Supongamos que creo una clase fábrica de bytes:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class ByteFactory{

    List<Byte> bytes;

    public ByteFactory(){
        bytes = IntStream.range(-128,128).mapToObj(i -> (Byte)(byte)i)
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
    }

    public Byte getByte(Byte byteInfo) {
        int index = bytes.indexOf(byteInfo);
        return bytes.get(index);
    }

}
```

¿Podría ahorrar memoria con esto?

Comment: no uses una lista usa un stream, ya sea stream de lectura o un stream del stream api, están pensados para una cantidad prácticamente infinita de datos. Eso te permitira hacer carga presoza al cargarlo solamente cuando se vaya usar. En tu codigo actual cargas todo en memoria asociandolo a un objeto sin hacer nasa con tu lista de bytes

Answer (score 1):

Varios puntos.

3 millones de bytes no son muchos. Si cada byte ocupara un byte (que no es el caso, un Byte ocupará algo más), serían 3Megas de memoria. Por defecto, java asigna una memoria a la máquina virtual dependiendo de la memoria disponible con un máximo de 512M. No sé si instancias muchas listas de 3Megas cada una. En cualquier caso, siempre puedes ampliar esa memoria disponible a más de 512M cambiando el Heap Space al arrancar la máquina virtual java.

Por otro lado, java es bastante "listo". La factoría que pretendes hacer de alguna forma ya la hace java. Para enteros es entre -128 y 127. Para los bytes para todos, ya que es justo ese rango. Fíjate en el siguiente código

```
public class Prueba {
public static void main(String [] args) {
    Byte a = (byte)3;
    Byte b = (byte)3;
    Byte c = new Byte((byte)3);
    System.out.println(a==b);
    System.out.println(a==c);
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(a));
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(b));
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(c));
}
```

}

a y b son la misma instancia, al convertir el byte a Byte de forma automática, java reutiliza la instancia del Byte de valor 3. Por ello, las salida de a==b es true y los identityHashCode de a y b son iguales. Las dos variables a y b ocupan el mismo espacio de memoria.

Pero si haces explicitamente un new de Byte, como en el caso de la variable c, entonces estas "forzando" una instancia distinta. Por ello a==c es false y el identityHashCode de c es distinto de a y b.

Quizás en tu código puedas asegurarte que no estás haciendo new de Byte en ningún lado, usando siempre "cast" de valores o variables byte a Byte.

Se bueno.